# Find the button code / reproduce the effect

Tags: jquery, wordpress, button, elementor

I'm looking for the jquery code that allows me to place "call" or "show number" on my [elementor](https://elementor.com/help/html-widget/) button because I need to hide the number.

[image]

like houzez does

[image]

[Source page](https://demo01.houzez.co/agent/brittany-watkins/)

I already have a code that was supposed to reproduce it..
but it doesn't work (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function)

I would like to know how to see or retrieve the code / script that houzez site uses..

on chrome dev I have a lot of trouble finding it ..

I know how to find css but not scripts .. don't know if it's already possible

**Any help will be welcome**

```
 <button data-number="123 345 565" class="phone-reveal">Call</button>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('.phone-reveal').on('click', function () {
                let phone = jQuery(this).data('number')
                jQuery(this).text(phone)
            });
        })
        
    </script>
```

my configuration
clean install wp 5.8 + elementor free
0 plugin and modification

**Update**

[image]

thanks for your code i can't get it to work properly

can you if possible test in the same dev environment as me? or any localhost dev

the fastest and easiest I use

[laragon](https://laragon.org/)

[wordpress 5.8](https://wordpress.org/download/)

[elementor free](https://wordpress.org/plugins/elementor/)

you really have to see it the button can not understand what is happening .. it does the reverse and the button changes completely instead of the text only.

it will be necessary to be in the same environment .. I have the impression that elementor always complicates the most obvious and simple manipulations. he doesn't want to listen to anything ...

sorry to expose very boring problems to solve..

if only we could see or extract the script that houzez made to their button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function uses the `$` function - which hasn't yet been defined. you need to explicitly define it in your elementor WP site.

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and alias in scope
  $('body').on("click", function(e) {
    let txt = "Call";
    if ($(e.target).hasClass('phone-reveal')) txt = $(e.target).data('number')
    $('button.phone-reveal').text(txt);
  });
});
```

```css
body{
background-color:#333;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-number="123 345 565" class="phone-reveal">Call</button>
```

Comment: Ok, it was working until i switched to currentTarget. Oddly... I do want to capture clicks anywhere on the page so I switched to body as a delegator. However e.currentTarget was not returning the button when I clicked on it. where as e.target is. See current iteration which works.

Comment: Currently your code only switches the number after a click. See the sample website, on mouseup the number goes back to the text "Call"

Comment: Hmmm. on the sample website (for me), it tries to launch skype when I click the button, but the # persists until I click elsewhere on the doc.

Comment: thanks for your code ! :) but .. i can't get it to work properly

look at the updated post

Comment: @neosan - I updated my answer... you must have the div or td that contains the button having the class 'phone-reveal'. I updated it to target only the button with that classname

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any JS at all.
Only CSS `:active` and the `::after` pseudo

```css
[data-number]:active span   {display: none;}
[data-number]:active::after {content: attr(data-number);}

/* irrelevant styles - only for this demo to pimp it up a bit */
button {
  color: #6ec1e4;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  min-width: 10em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-number="123 345 565"><span>Call</span></button>
```